# Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\usercontrol.xml" to ".\bin\usercontrol.xml". Access to the path 'obj\Debug\usercontrol.xml' is denied

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am doing project in vb.net .i am getting above error.Unable to copy file & access to file path is denied.
When i close project & open it again it starts normally & suddenly for one build same error comes
What is the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the file is locked by another process, hence the access denied message.  Make sure that the program isn't running when you try to build again.  If the program isn't running and you still get that error on build, I would do what you did - close and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it so happens that even if you remove the file being used by another process, it still shows the error. In that case, go to the project's properties and under build events tab add the code in the pre build text box:

```
if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"
if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" if exist "$(TargetPath)" move "$(TargetPath)"        
"$(TargetPath).locked"
```

Hope this helps someone.